# If IE not working properly

Tags: internet-explorer, css, conditional-comments

I have 1 div and i want to apply a gradient and a background image to it (yes, on the same element). I know that it's only possible if the browser you`re targeting is NOT IE. With that in mind, i thought of applying a solid color in stead of the gradient with an image on top of it for IE only.

Here is my code:

```
background: url(../images/newsletter.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(10,10,01) , rgb(5,5,5));
background: url(../images/newsletter.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0a0a0a), to(#05050f));
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
<!--[if IE]>
background: #000 url(../images/newsletter.png) center left no-repeat;
<![endif]-->
```

The problem is the condition is ignored, before or after the declaration for FF/Chrome. (i`ve tested the  and also the [if false] etc.)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't put that kind of conditional in CSS; it goes in your HTML. So create a new stylesheet with the IE fix, and link to it in a conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

for example. *However*, that's in general; you can rewrite what you have now as:

```css
background-color: black;
background-image: url(../images/newsletter.png);
background-image: url(../images/newsletter.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(10,10,01) , rgb(5,5,5));
background-image: url(../images/newsletter.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0a0a0a), to(#05050f));
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

which degrades gracefully without ugly conditional comments, and doesn't exclusively degrade gracefully on Internet Explorer.

Comment: One more thing: If you really have to use a conditional comment, you should specify a version, like this: `<!--[if lte IE 9]>`. Otherwise, future versions will continue to use your hack. See here for more examples: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, thank you! Also, thanks for the clarification with the IE conditional statement.  @VainFellowman Thanks for the tip.